# Installing typings for underscore

Tags: angularjs, underscore.js

I have been taking a course on Udemy.com where the author is having me install underscore in the final project to demonstrate how to use it.  These are the step that he stated to use (which I have followed).

1. Install `underscore`.

   ```
    $npm install underscore –save
   ```
2. reference the script in `index.html`

   ```
    <script src=”node_modules/underscore/underscore.js”></script>
   ```
3. Install typings

   ```
   $npm install –g typings.
   ```

   Do I need to install this for every project? I did that once before for another project, I thought that was a system install of typing and not just for a project.
4. Install the type definition

   ```
   $typings install underscore --ambient
   ```

Note: when I tried step 4. I get a message that 'ambient' has been deprecated and that I should use 'global'.  So I thought ok `$typings install underscore --global`.  Now I get all these errors (which I'm clueless about).

```
typings ERR! message Unable to find "underscore" ("npm") in the registry.
typings ERR! message However, we found "underscore" for 1 other source: "dt"
typings ERR! message You can install these using the "source" option.
typings ERR! message We could use your help adding these typings to the registry: https://github.com/typings/registry
typings ERR! caused by "api.typings.org/entries/npm/underscore/versions/latest" responded with 404, expected it to equal 200




typings ERR! cwd C:\Users\bob\Desktop\Final Project
typings ERR! system Windows_NT 6.1.7601
typings ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\bob\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\typings\\dist\\bin.js" "install" "underscore" "--global"
typings ERR! node -v v4.5.0
typings ERR! typings -v 1.4.0




typings ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
typings ERR!   github.com/typings/typings/issues
```

Would anyone know what I'm doing wrong with trying to install typings?

Comment: Note:  I tried  "$typings install underscore --global --save"   and I received the same errors.

Comment: are you using the latest version of angular-cli? in this case you should get rid of the old typings and get the @types version of them - more here: https://microsoft.github.io/TypeSearch/

Answer (score 0):

I found this:

```
typings install dt~underscore --global --save
```

and it worked for me, no errors running that command. It brings IntelliSense of the Underscore library.